# How can I use my currentDate variable to set the arrival date in the asp.net textbox control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Request.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx06Reservation.Request" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Chapter 6: Reservations</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            display: block;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #555;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-image: none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
            -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
            -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
            transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 1112px;
            height: 64px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="jumbotron">
            <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="Royal Inns and Suites" />
        </header>

        <main>
            <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
                <h1>Reservation Request</h1>

                <h3>Request data</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Arrival Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtArrivalDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"
                              Height="39px" Width="186px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Departure Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- text box -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" Height="39px" Width="186px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Number of people</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- drop-down -->
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Height="39px" Width="186px">
                       <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bed type</label>
                    <div class="auto-style2">
                        <!-- radio buttons -->
&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="King" Selected="True" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Two Queens"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server"  Text="One Queen"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h3>Special requests</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <!-- multiline text box -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Width="334px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h3>Contact information</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="153px" Height="36px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- text box -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="158px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- text box -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="159px" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Telephone number</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- text box -->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="155px" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Preferred method</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <!-- drop down -->
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1"  Width="155px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Email</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Telephone</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <%-- Submit and Clear buttons --%>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"
                             CssClass="btn btn-primary"  />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear"
                             CssClass="btn btn-primary"  />
                    </div>
                </div> 
            
                <%-- message label --%>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="text-info"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
                Royal Inns and Suites</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to figure out how can I use the `currentDate` variable to set an arrival date (like October 10, 2017 - 10/10/2017) in that control's box everytime the page loads. Here is my code that I have tried on my own, but everytime I test the page, nothing is automatically put into that control's textbox. Can someone help me? Any others sources other then this (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-populate-date-automatically-in-a-text-box-in-asp-net)?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XEx06Reservation
{
    public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string currentDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("d"); 
        private string currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

                txtArrivalDate.Text = currentDate; 

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: @Federico Dipuma  Can u help me?

Comment: About code should display `9/23/2017` *depending on the language preference of Windows*. What is it not working, and what is your expected result?

Comment: @Win I want to automatically set a predefined date 10/10/2017 into the text arrival date control on my webpage everytime the page loads. but it just gets outputting mm/dd/yyyy. Can you help me?

Comment: `txtArrivalDate` is a textbox or some other control such as datepicker or something?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya  it's a textbox that you can select a date and it will be placed in the textbox. I post my aspx code as well.

Comment: This is the only code you have in Page_Load? Please share if there is also some other code which is executed in Page_Load.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya This is the only code that's inside of this event handler.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Is it a problem since I used the variable to refer to how I want to  format the date in the textbox? Can I even use a private variable in this matter?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Are you still there?

Comment: I just tried your code. We are getting current date inside the textbox. What else do you require?

Comment: @Deepak That's not what I wanted. I say it needs to be automatically preset to October 10, 2017.  It should say in the textbox 10-10-2017; not M/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Does that mean you want a date format or you want a constant date (10-10-2017) inside textbox?

Comment: @Deepak A constant date (10-10-2017) please. Do you think you can help? It should be predefined everytime I load the page. Meaning this date will populate automatically when the user refresh the page or loads the page for the first time.

Comment: `nothing is automatically put into that control's textbox. Can someone help me?` isn't it misleading? Everyone here (at least me) assumes that nothing is getting displayed in the textbox and not OP says that the date is not being displayed in the textbox and trying to find solution around that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:-

In Your .aspx page:-

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtArrivalDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In your .aspx.cs page:-

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static readonly DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(2017, 10, 10);
    private string currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtArrivalDate.Text = currentDate.ToString();
        lblYear.Text = currentYear;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Deepak-But how can I use my existing variable named currentDate to do this?

Comment: Edited My Answer.

Comment: @Deepak-Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it Helped. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Deepak-Can I ask one question though? How would I get 2017 after the copyright symbol in my web form?

Comment: You can use a label and on page load assign it's value to currentYear. Like :- lblYear.Text=currentYear; I would prefer doing this on my master page .

Comment: @Deepak-I did this private string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("yyyy"); then lblYear.Text = currentYear; But this doesn't work.

Comment: Check my modified answer please.

Comment: @DeepakThis doesn't do anything  txtArrivalDate.Text = currentDate.ToString();

Comment: I run this code and this is giving me the desired result. Have you modified the code after it was executed successfully last time?

Comment: @ Deepak-just semantic error which means it does not load the predefined date. It does load the 2017 on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155173/discussion-between-deepak-and-dorakta).